# GeoListPlot - Workaround for distinct coloring of categories - improvement?

Tags: bugs, geographics, workaround

[GeoListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoListPlot.html) supports multiple lists of locations but once the number of lists exceeds 3, the coloring function for the categories starts to recycle the colors. For example, adding a list to the example of the documentation produces the map below

```
data= {{Entity["Country", "Bulgaria"], Entity["Country", "Greece"]}, {Entity["Country", "Albania"], Entity["Country", "Romania"]},{Entity["Country", "Turkey"], Entity["Country", "Lebanon"]}, {Entity["Country", "Israel"], Entity["Country", "Syria"]}}; 

GeoListPlot[data]
```

[image: GeoListPlot with 4 categories]

This was reported some time ago to Wolfram (CASE: 41535576) but it still an issue in version 12.

My current work around is to define a list of colors and to use the [Directive](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html) function. An example:

```
colors = Table[
   ColorData["SunsetColors"][i], {i, 0, 1, 1/((Length@data - 1))}]; 
plotStylesDef = Directive[#, Opacity[0.6]] & /@ colors; 
GeoListPlot[data, GeoLabels -> None, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> plotStylesDef]
```

[image]

My question is: how can this workaround be improved? (More robust, overload the original function, better selection of ColorData..)

Comment: you can also do: `GeoListPlot[data, PlotStyle->(Opacity[.6,ColorData["SunsetColors"]@#]&/@Subdivide[0,1,Length[data]-1])]`

Comment: In version 12.2.0.0 this is fixed. But I still find the workaround useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`ColorData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html)with an `"Indexed"` color scheme. These can be viewed in from the menu Palettes | Color Schemes palette.  They can be referenced by their index or their name.

Both

```
GeoListPlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[98] /@ Range@Length@data]
```

and

```
GeoListPlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[{"Indexed", "Earth"}] /@ Range@Length@data]
```

give

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

These colour indices repeat themselves when the requested colour exceeds the numer of colours in the `"ColorList"` so you should pick one that has a reasonable amount in them.  For schemes with more than 10 colours,

```
Select[Length@ColorData[#, "ColorList"] > 10 &]@ColorData["Indexed"]
```

However, if you are set on using a `"Gradient"` colour scheme then you may use [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html).

```
GeoListPlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale@Range@Length@data]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant w Rescale! Straightforward to add the Directive[.., Opacity[]] (...PlotStyle-> (Directive[#, 0.6]&/@(ColorData[..]@...)). The reason for that construct is for the PlotLegend's color to better match the color on the map. Also I didn't think about that search for the indexed colors with more than e.g. 10 values. .

Comment: in v12.3, this code won't work: `GeoListPlot[data, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[{"Indexed", "Earth"}] /@ Range@Length@data]`: all in the same colour. Seems to be a bug?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the fact that the internal function `` System`GeoPlotsDump`defaultPlotStyle[] `` used by `GeoListPlot[]` is working with a somewhat limited color selection. For obvious reasons, I won't copy the definition of this internal function here; instead, let me propose a possible replacement function:

```
myDefaultPlotStyle[i_Integer][l_Integer] := 
  Table[Directive[ColorData[i, k], EdgeForm[Directive[Thin, Opacity[0.4]]],
                  PointSize[Large], FaceForm[Opacity[0.5]]], {k, l}]
```

which uses the indexed colors supported by `ColorData[]`. (You can of course replace `ColorData[i, k]` with some other function that generates an indexed color list.)

Then, for instance,

```
Block[{System`GeoPlotsDump`defaultPlotStyle = myDefaultPlotStyle[61]},
      GeoListPlot[data]]
```

[image: plot example 1]

```
Block[{System`GeoPlotsDump`defaultPlotStyle = myDefaultPlotStyle[97]},
      GeoListPlot[List /@ Flatten[data]]]
```

[image: plot example 2]

Comment: Clever, I didn't know you could do this.

Comment: Great, so one way WRI can fix the bug is to replace the internal function with something in line your "myDefault..." combined with making sure that the indexed colors scheme choosen have enough different values.